# How to access instance variables in CoffeeScript engine inside a Slim template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, haml, slim-lang

I have a Rails controller in which I am setting a instance variable -

```
@user_name = "Some Username"
```

In my .slim template I am using coffee engine to generate javascript and want to print out the user name from client-sie javascript code -

```
coffee:
  $(document).ready ->
    name = "#{@user_name}"
    alert name
```

But this is the javascript that is being generated??

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var name;
    name = "" + this.my_name;
    alert(name);
}
```

**How do I access controller instance variables in my CoffeeScript code??**

I am tagging this as haml since I am guessing haml will have the same issue when using CoffeeScript .

Comment: @Thilo No, he's trying to inject the Ruby variable `@user_name`. Ruby and CoffeeScript use the same string interpolation syntax.

Comment: I see. BTW, how come the variable name changes from `"#{@user_name}"
` to `this.my_name` ?

Comment: Because in coffeescript, @prop gets compiled to this.prop

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560864/performance-implications-of-using-coffescript-filter-inside-haml-templates/19501683#19501683 Similar question/solution

Answer (score 94, accepted):

What's happening is that `"#{@user_name}"` is being interpreted as CoffeeScript, not as Ruby code that's evaluated and injected into the CoffeeScript source. You're asking, "How do I inject a Ruby variable into my CoffeeScript source?"

The short answer is: Don't do this. The Rails team made an intentional decision not to support embedded CoffeeScript in templates in 3.1, because there's significant performance overhead to having to compile CoffeeScript on every request (as you'd have to do if you allowed arbitrary strings to be injected into the source).

My advice is to serve your Ruby variables separately as pure JavaScript, and then reference those variables from your CoffeeScript, e.g.:

```
javascript:
  user_name = "#{@user_name}";
coffee:
  $(document).ready ->
    name = user_name
    alert name
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, so basically what you have suggested is ok from performance perspective?

Comment: That depends on whether Slim recompiles the CoffeeScript in the template on every request. I'm honestly not sure. You should probably move it to an external file anyway; then it'll only be compiled to JS once, and browsers will cache it.

Answer (score 32):

I tend to avoid inline javascript at all costs.

A nice way to store variables in your HTML, to be used from your javascript, is to use the HTML5 data-attributes. This is ideal to keep your javascript unobtrusive.

Comment: That wouldn't be helpful if you're using a JavaScript MVC and want to avoid making multiple HTTP requests to the server. http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap

Comment: If you are using javascript MVC, you mostly do ajax requests to get the data, and render the html on the client anyway. But for instance, general config params you can still send once in data attributes in the html/body/container.

Comment: True, true. Sorry if I came off very rash!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use:

```
$(document).ready ->
  name = <%= JSON.generate @user_name %>
  alert name
```

This is because [JSON](http://www.json.org/) is a subset of JavaScript.

Comment: This barfs hard.  Or at least does inside Dashing .coffee files.