# Calling ruby code from coffee: slim tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, slim-lang

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access instance variables in CoffeeScript engine inside a Slim template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108511/how-to-access-instance-variables-in-coffeescript-engine-inside-a-slim-template)

How can I use Ruby code in my coffee tags?

`#{}` is a slim construction to call Ruby code, but it doesn't work in coffee tag, because `#´ is used to begin a comment in CoffeeScript.

```
coffee:
     window.awesomeIcons.currentUser = #{raw current_user.to_json} #Doesn't work
```

What to do?

Answer (score 2):

To put it simply - it's not possible (at least not directly). Have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/stonean/slim/issues/179) on Slim's issue tracker. This is the relavant bit by @minad (one of Slim's devs):

> It is not possible to implement this because coffee script is
>   transformed at compile time. You could only embed normal javascript.
>   To avoid confusion we didn't implement interpolation in the coffee
>   filter.

I'd suggest using the [gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon) to expose a JavaScript variable from your Rails controller than you can directly access in the Coffee filter later on.

Comment: Thanks. Gon was very useful gem=)