# Coffeescript access to current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm writing a Rails app.

In CoffeeScript, I would like to access the current_user along with it's relationship to an employee.

This is the code I'm trying:

```
    $.create "/events/",
      event:
        title: title,
        starts_at: "" + start,
        ends_at: "" + end,
        all_day: allDay,
        hours: hours,
        employee_id: current_user.employee_id
        # pickup the current employee
```

But, the console shows - Uncaught ReferenceError: current_user is not defined

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the gem 'gon' , which is useful for passing data from ruby to coffee in rails application . Here is [the Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?autoplay=true) about gon's usage , and this is the [repository of 'Gon'](https://github.com/gazay/gon).

Comment: Gon would work.  But, while watching the railscast, I saw that I could just use the <%= content_tag "div", id: "calendar", data: {employeeid: current_user.employee.id} do %>

Answer (score 7):

If you are writing coffescript **inside rails assets pipeline** (which I believe you do) you **cannot** access current_user at all. The problem here is that assets are precompiling once when you deploy to prod env (or on the first access in dev env). All subsequent requests just link to the precompiled js bundle. So js code is the same for all requests. On the other hand, current_user is specific for each request. So, in order to access current_user from the assets pipeline js code you have to request it from a specific server api method via some ajax call.

The other possible option is you are writing a coffeescript as controller action view template. In this case you should add .erb preprocessor. You'll get a file like **app/views/controller_name/action_name.js.coffee.erb** with

```
$.create "/event",
  event:
    employee_id: <%= current_user.employee_id %>
```

Hope this will help

Comment: That's interesting -- I didn't know you could add the erb to coffeescript.

Comment: you can add .erb to *anything*. When doing so, read the extensions form right to left : my_file.js.coffee.erb is an erb file that will generate a coffee file that will generate a js file which is going to be served to the client.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that `current_user` in this context is a Ruby value that you're trying to access (a controller instance variable, or, based on the name, probably a Devise method that returns the current user object).  This isn't going to be visible in JavaScript/CoffeeScript.  You can set it in a view (e.g. ERB) and then access it in other JavaScript functions.

Check out [this other Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108511/how-to-access-instance-variables-in-coffeescript-engine-inside-a-slim-template) for some good pointers on how to do this, including a link to a Railscast episode.

The short answer is that you'll probably want something like this in an ERB template:

```
<script>
    employee_id = <%= current_user.employee_id %>
</script>
```

Note that you can't just assign `current_user` to a JavaScript variable and then call methods on that from JS; it just doesn't work that way.  You can't access Ruby/Rails values in JS; you have to store values that JS understands (scalars, JSON, whatever).

Comment: This doesn't work because the assets are precompiled **before** you access `employee_id` in your coffescript file, so you get `undefined local variable or method employee_id'`...

Comment: @prograils it should work if the `script` tag comes before the included coffeescript file. Having said that, I prefer to include the variable in a `data-` attribute in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest 3 options. But all of them are not secure:

1. Some AJAX call from coffee to server (I haven't tried it).
2. Rendering `user_id` as an attribute of a tag in your HTML view then acquiring it via jQuery in your coffee file. See https://www.sitepoint.com/create-a-chat-app-with-rails-5-actioncable-and-devise/

HTML:

```
<div id="user_id" data-user-id="<%= current_user.id %>">
```

CoffeeScript:

```
tag_user_id = $('#user_id')
current_user_id = tag_user_id.data('user-id')
```

3. Setting `user_id` in plain cookie at login procedure and reading that cookie from inside coffee file as JS call `document.cookie`. If you use Devise, implement a Warden hook like here: https://rubytutorial.io/actioncable-devise-authentication/

app/config/initializers/warden_hooks.rb

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user do |user,auth,opts|
  scope = opts[:scope]
  auth.cookies["#{scope}.id"] = user.id # not signed
end
```

CoffeeScipt:

```
current_user_id = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)user.id\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
```