# Performance implications of using :coffescript filter inside HAML templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, haml

So [HAML 4 includes a coffeescript filter](http://blog.haml.info/post/42998475354/haml-4-0-has-been-released), which allows us coffee-loving rails people to do neat things like this:

```
- word = "Awesome."

:coffeescript
  $ ->
    alert "No semicolons! #{word}"
```

My question: For the end user, is this slower than using the equivalent `:javascript` filter? Does using the coffeescript filter mean the coffeescript will be compiled to javascript on every page load (which would obviously be a performance disaster), or does this only happen once when the application is started?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends.

When Haml compiles a filter it checks to see if the filter text [contains any interpolation](https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/4.0.3/lib/haml/filters.rb#L163) (`#{...}`). If there isn’t any then it will be the same text to transform on each request, so the conversion is done once at compile time and the result included in the template.

If there *is* interpolation in the filter text, then the actual text to transform will vary on each request, so the Coffeescript will need to be compiled each time.

Here’s an example. First with no interpolation:

```haml
:coffeescript
  $ ->
    alert "No semicolons! Awesome"
```

This generates the code (use `haml -d` to see the generated Ruby code):

```ruby
_hamlout.buffer << "<script>\n  (function() {\n    $(function() {\n      return alert(\"No semicolons! Awesome\");\n    });\n  \n  }).call(this);\n</script>\n";
```

This code simply adds a string to the buffer, so no Coffeescript is being recompiled.

Now with interpolation:

```haml
- word = "Awesome."

:coffeescript
  $ ->
    alert "No semicolons! #{word}"
```

This generates:

```ruby
 word = "Awesome."
_hamlout.buffer << "#{
find_and_preserve(Haml::Filters::Coffee.render_with_options(
"$ ->
  alert \"No semicolons! #{word}\"\n", _hamlout.options))
}\n";
```

Here, since Haml needs to wait to see what the value of the interpolation is, the Coffeescript is recompiled each time.

You can avoid compiling the Coffeescript on each request by not having any interpolation inside your `:coffeescript` filters.

The `:javascript` filter behaves similarly, checking to see if there is any interpolation, but since the `:javascript` filter only outputs some text to the buffer when it runs there is much less of a performance hit using it. You could possibly combine `:javascript` and `:coffeescript` filters, putting interpolated data in `:javascript` and keeping your `:coffeescript` static:

```haml
- word = "Awesome"

:javascript
  var message = "No semicolons! #{word}";

:coffeescript
  alert message
```

Comment: Fantastic response. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

matt's answer is clear on what is going on. I made a helper to add locals to `:coffeescript` filters from a hash. This way you don't need to use global JavaScript variables. As a side note: on Linux, the slowdown is really negligible. On Windows however, the impact on performance is quite important (easily more than 100ms per block to compile).

```
module HamlHelper
  def coffee_with_locals locals={}, &block
    block_content = capture_haml do
      block.call
    end

    return block_content if locals.blank?

    javascript_locals = "\nvar "
    javascript_locals << locals.map{ |key, value| j(key.to_s) + ' = ' + value.to_json.gsub('</', '<\/') }.join(",\n    ")
    javascript_locals << ";\n"

    content_node = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(block_content)
    content_node.search('script').each do |script_tag|
      # This will match the '(function() {' at the start of coffeescript's compiled code
      split_coffee = script_tag.content.partition(/\(\s*function\s*\(\s*\)\s*\{/)
      script_tag.content = split_coffee[0] + split_coffee[1] +  javascript_locals + split_coffee[2]
    end

    content_node.to_s.html_safe
  end
end
```

It allows you to do the following:

```
= coffee_with_locals "test" => "hello ", :something => ["monde", "mundo", "world"], :signs => {:interogation => "?", :exclamation => "!"} do
  :coffeescript
    alert(test + something[2] + signs['exclamation'])
```

Since there is no interpollation, the code is actually compiled as normal.